# The "other" finger (GECOS fields at /etc/passwd)

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, c, finger

in the file `/etc/passwd` we have the so called `GECOS fields` (which stands for "General Electric Comprehensive Operating System"), that is:

```
username:password:userid:groupid:gecos:home-dir:shell
```

Where `GECOS` are divided as:

```
:FullName,RoomAddress,WorkPhone,HomePhone,Others:
```

And `Others` are divided in as many commas as you like:

```
:FullName,RoomAddress,WorkPhone,HomePhone,Other1,Other2,Other3:
```

In the `man chfn` pages one can read:

> The other field is used to store accounting information used by other
>   applications.

Now, for an application developer (I'm interested in `C language`, `system calls` and/or `bash script`) which is the best way to grab this information?

And considering just the `Bash` environment, given that `finger` command cannot display the `others` fields (or at least I don't see how), what are other commands that can? I know that `chfn` not only show, but allow them to be changed. What if one is to just output it to `stdout`?

Comment: For example in bash you can extract the field with `awk -F ":" '{print $5}' /etc/passwd` ... then you can process again the string (you can do with a single call too via `split`ting the field with the split function.

Comment: I was wondering if I could use a command specific to the job, instead of text processing commands (`awk`, `sed`, `cat`, `grep`, `cut`, and alike). Also, how applications would read this? Any example of an application that do use the `other` field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way i have found is to use `getent` because that will work with LDAP/NIS or other methods of non local users

```
getent passwd $UID| awk -F ":" '{print $5}'
```

Comment: If you just want the user's name, you can do `getent passwd $UID | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d, -f1` (basically this says: cut the 5th field separated by `:` and then cut the 1st field separated by `,`).

Answer (score 1):

For example in a bash script you can print the fifth field of the file `/etc/passwd` with awk/gawk:

```
awk -F ":" '{print $5}' /etc/passwd
```

The option `-F fs` uses fs for the input field separator (in this case `:`).
You can read more, for example, on the GNU awk homepage  <sup>[[1](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)]</sup>.
Awk has the function `split()` to split a string (where in this case you will use the 5th field as string and the `,` as separator). Take insipiration from some other answer about it <sup>[[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8009724/3569208)]...</sup>.

Comment: This command would give the whole `GECOS` field. But its a starting point for an answer.

Comment: This _"just output to the stdout"_. From here, using the tip of the `split ()` function you can start to write your script...

Answer (score 1):

You can just use two nested cut commands:

- first with ":" as the field separator, cut field 1 & 5; and
- second with "," as the field separator, cut fields 1 & 5-N;